# How do I install this package on a Linux (Centos) machine?

Tags: linux, github, installation, centos

I found this package on GitHub ([doctotext](https://github.com/karlproject/doctotext)). I'd like to install it on my Centos-running dedicated server (x86_64), but I do not know how. Could someone offer instructions as to how I could do it. There are no instructions provided, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Makefile](https://github.com/karlproject/doctotext/blob/master/Makefile), so try to:

- `git clone` the repo anywhere you want (typically within your home account)

  ```
  cd
  git clone https://github.com/karlproject/doctotext
  cd doctotext
  ```
- type `make` and `make install`

You will then see if you can build and install it by compilation.

Comment: 1) What I did was add the folder to /root ... 2) I then entered the folder: cd doctotext ... 3) I typed: make ... 4) I get an error: Makefile:1: /common/src/make/Makefile.inc: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/common/src/make/Makefile.inc'.  Stop. **What does this mean?**

Comment: @stylusss no need to use root. You might have to use `sudo make install`. As for the error message, open an issue to ask his/her author: https://github.com/karlproject/doctotext/issues

Comment: It hasn't been updated in 2 years, that's why I tried my luck here instead. Additionally, I tried `sudo make install` but it didn't work. I know this is a lot to ask, but could you try it on your server?

Comment: @stylusss the sudo part is only to be made once a successfull build (with make) has been done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to considering alternatives, which are actively maintained, I recommend

PDFMiner http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html

It includes pdf2txt.py which may be a good solution for you.

If you are looking for other options or additional formats browse

https://pypi.org/search/?q=documents

I'm sure you'll find something.

Comment: This only does PDFs. Need a complete solution to my document needs